# Iterating over dataframe column and creating new column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this `DataFrame`

[image]

I want to create a new column(seq) and do the following things

- `df['seq']` = First item of every group(by id) is 0
- `df['seq']` = Keep Increment until you see a Date in the date column by group(by id)
- if date is present reset the column seq to 0 again follow the same increment process

This is my expected answer expected output:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution it comes to me is to create an array and fill it with the value of a `counter` when you loop over your dataframe. You will add the new column after.

For example:

```
seq = np.zeros(len(df))
date = ''
id = 0
counter = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    test_date = df['Dates'].iloc[i]
    test_id = df['id'].iloc[i]
    if (test_date and test_date != date) or (test_id != id):
        # new date or id detected
        date = test_date
        id = test_id
        counter = 0
    else:
        counter += 1
    seq[i] = counter

df['seq'] = seq
```

It might be a more efficient way to do that, but from my experience, performances are ok when using numpy array to add data in dataframe.